# Regex to find specific pattern string from string

Tags: java, regex

How to get `ricCode:.ABC` from following string.
My matcher is

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("ricCode:([A-Za-z]+),$").matcher(str);

String str = "{AMX:{ricCode:.ABC,indexDetailEnable:true,price:20,648.15,netChange:<spanclass="md-down">-41.09</span>,percentChange:<spanclass="md-down">-0.20％</span>,tradeDate:17/04/05,tradeTime:16:40,chartDate:17/04/05,chartTime:16:40}";
```

What is missing in the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex from this:

```
ricCode:([A-Za-z]+),$
```

to this:

```
ricCode:([A-Za-z.]+)(?=,)
```

Your original regex would only allow alphabetic characters after `ricCode:`, but your example has a period `.` character. Also you were matching the `,` character, but this would also include the comma in your match, you dont want this - so I added a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the comma so it looks for it there but does not match it. Finally you had the `$` character at the end of your regex which matches the end of the string, you dont want to look for the end of the string immediately after the comma, so I removed it.

It helps to use [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) to test out your expression.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I have added and trying to print substring but getting IllegalArgumentError. I am trying to print getting IllegalArgumentException. `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("ricCode:([A-Za-z.]+)(?=,)").matcher(test);
   while (matcher.find()) {
    String str = test.substring(matcher.start("ricCode:"),matcher.end());
    System.out.println("value :: "+str);
   }`

Comment: Sorry I was printing it in wrong way. `System.out.println("value :: "+ matcher.group())` correct way. Thanks a lot

Comment: how will be the regex to get anything after `ricCode:` till comma ?

Comment: You could use this: `(?<=ricCode:)[^,]+(?=,)`, it uses positive lookbehind to find `ricCode:` but doesnt include it in the match, then looks for 1 or more characters that are not `,` and then positive lookahead for your `,`

Comment: @user2811650 if my answer is right and helped you i'd appreciate if you could mark it as the accepted answer and upvote. Thanks!